# Creating a message for write to a TCP socket

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, boost-asio

I don't really know how to put this question, but here we go.

So let's assume I'm using ASIO from Boost libs to connect to a server using a TCP socket and write a certain message to it.

The message contains some user data and looks like this: 1 byte (packet ID), 4 bytes (integer), user null-terminated string and 6 zero bytes (reserved by the server but unused).

What would be the most convenient way to assemble such a message for use with ASIO's boost::asio::buffer function?

I'm really confused at this point. Help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your message is a string or structure?

Comment: That's what I actually can't decide with. I have tried using a string, but I'm not sure what would be the most appropriate way to fill it with necessary byte data, and especially if it's at all the best option to go with, assuming ASIO reference states that it may work just as well with std::vector or std::string.

I thought of using a struct for this, but I'm not totally sure about how to do it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A. Define packet structures that can be serialized.

```
class ISerializable
{
public:
    virtual ~ISerializable(){}

    virtual void serialize(std::ostream& stream) = 0;
};

class LoginPacket : public ISerializable
{
public:
    // Constructor and access functions

    virtual void serialize(std::ostream& stream)
    {
        stream.write((const char*)&packetId, 1);
        stream.write((const char*)&accountId, 4);
        stream.write(username.c_str(), username.size() + 1);
        // Write the unused 6-bytes of zero
        int zero(0);
        stream.write((const char*)&zero, 4);
        stream.write((const char*)&zero, 2);
    }

private:
    unsigned char packetId;
    unsigned int32_t accountId;
    std::string username;
};
```

B. Now, to use this packet class do something like:

```
LoginPacket packet;
// Fill details for the packet
std::stringstream data;
packet.serialize(data);
// Send the data to the network
yourSocket.send(data.str().c_str(), data.str().size());
```

Comment: Is `&int(0)` a C++11 thing, or have I never known this existed in C++?

Comment: I wouldn't use a stream for a binary protocol. A stream buffer seams more appropriate here. And there seams to be no use for virtual functions, at least not, unless there are some kind of polymorphic data structures to be serialized.

Comment: >stream.write(&accountId, 4); makes this implementation highly implementation dependent.

Comment: @TorstenRobitzki: I have been using it in my networking library with no issues so far. It's interacting with a server created in C, which was not coded by me. Also, `stream.write(&accountId, 4);` is basically writing a binary data and not a text data.

Comment: @TorstenRobitzki: Here's an example: http://ideone.com/U82Se. Had it been written as text data the size would be 1 not 4.

Comment: @ViteFalcon Simply writing an integer by writing the first 4 bytes of it's integer representation has two problems: First, an int don't have to be 4 bytes. This can even change from one version to the next of the same compiler. If you are lucky, and the size became 8 bytes, you wrote the "right" half of the int. I would recommend to use at least "sizeof int". The other problem is the representation of the int in memory (little endian, big endian etc.). This will likely be the same on the same platform, but as we are speaking about networking, this might be different on the reading side.

Comment: Thanks, this is a rather interesting solution. I'm likely to use it.

Comment: @TorstenRobitzki: Even though this might have been an issue, the server application I'm connecting to has fixed variable sizes (int - 4 bytes, short - 2 bytes, etc.), so this isn't a huge problem. But thanks anyway.

Comment: @TorstenRobitzki Or use `int32_t` etc.

Comment: @JamesMcLaughlin Yes, on the lower network layer it makes sense to talk in "network-units".

Comment: @TorstenRobitzki: An int is guaranteed to be atleast 4 bytes for a 32-bit/64-bit environment. I had made that assumption seeing that he's using boost tags and boost::asio. No matter which half-part of the int it writes, 0 is still all 0's in both halves. So this solution works no matter what you think. Your solution of writing with sizeof(int) causes the issue of writing 8 bytes in 64-bit environment, while he specifically said he wanted to write 6 zero bytes at the end.

Comment: @ViteFalcon I was more concerned with the 'write((const char*)&accountId, 4);' expression. If accountId has a sizeof 8 bytes, it might not work.

Comment: @TorstenRobitzki: It still works for that as well. The only other concern I would have is with big-endian environments, in which case he'd have to use `htonl()`. The reason I'm sure it works is because my network library works on both 32 and 64 bits with no issues as you've mentioned.
EDIT: Correction, I'm using int32_t though.

Comment: @ViteFalcon What happens when username contains a \0 in the middle? ;-)

Comment: @TorstenRobitzki: Then he has an issue with his access function that fills the username. Or his code. :). Now you're being desperate to find issues?

Comment: @ViteFalcon Or someone using utf-8 encoding ;-)

Comment: @TorstenRobitzki: That'd still be an issue to be dealt with by the coder. AFAIK, std::string reports the size of the data it uses with `size()` and I haven't sepcified `length()` to determine the size of string data to be sent. So if his string has a size of 50, utf-8 or not, the whole string will go through.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of making a single buffer using `asio::buffer()` function, you can adapt your structure to be a [buffer sequence](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ConstBufferSequence.html) - asio functions accept such a concept. It would be convenient to send this way a pattern like fixed--null-terminated--null-terminated-fixed-fixed-etc...

Comment: It would be great if you could demonstrate how to do that with a simple example. I'm curious to see an example and wondering if it would be advantageous to use it for myself.

Answer (score 1):

the boost::asio::buffer() functions adapt or convert other kind of buffers to the one, used by asio.

You should use some kind of application buffer, fill that buffer and then pass the buffer to asio for writing onto the wire. For example:

```
std::vector< char > data;

data.push_back( id );
data.push_back( i & 0xff );
data.push_back( ( i >> 8 ) & 0xff );
data.push_back( ( i >> 16 ) & 0xff );
data.push_back( ( i >> 24 ) & 0xff );

const char* const str = s.c_str();
data.insert( data.end(), str, str + std::strlen( str ) );

for ( int pad = 0; pad != 4; ++pad )
    data.push_back( 0 );

boost::asio::write( socket, boost::asio::buffer( data ) );
```

Comment: Wouldn't there be a way to write non-character types in a more compact way?

Comment: @InsomniaArray it depends on your requirements. But defining the binary protocol down to the lowest bit seems to be a not to much work. How much different primitive data type do you habe? A bool, an int and a string? That are 3 functions, taking some kind of buffer and the data to be written. That will cost you 10 minutes now and might save you hours latter, when someone ask you to support old Mac and Alpha computers ;-)

Comment: True, although I don't intend to have a public release or anything. But then again, who knows what path I will go. Thanks.

Comment: Of all solutions (I haven't seen the an example from Igor), this one looks the most complicated.